# How to understand if a bigint is signed or unsigned in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table whose create statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE `takas` (
  `TAKAS_NO` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `FIYAT` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,
  `MIKTAR` decimal(20,5) NOT NULL) 

...
```

is TAKAS_NO a signed bigint or unsigned? I couldn't find the answer in web.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All ints are signed unless you specify that they're unsigned:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
   x int // signed
   y int unsigned // unsigned
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. 
All ints are signed

for detail see this link
http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/bigint-v-int-is-there-a-big-deal-2008-07-18/

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html